# Обрезать спец. символ С#

Tags: c#, .net

На сайте есть вот такая вот строка.

[image: Символ который нужно обрезать]

в string из неё вытягивается следующее: 
"_Linked_5d2c9d64b(и два пробела в конце)", то есть картинка в конце строки (которую я обвёл) вытягивается тоже как пробел.

Эти пробелы нужно обрезать. Обычный Trim() метод не хочет это делать, так как он не считает пробел на месте картинки обычным пробелом.

Подскажите, может можно trim() перегрузить каким-то char`ом, который бы обозначал этот "необычный" пробел и удалял его?

Comment: А почему нельзя обрезать строку на два последних символа?

Comment: Ну так посмотри в отладчике, что там за символы.

Comment: Скорее всего там какой-нибудь неразрывный пробел.

Comment: Посмотрел, там действительно два неразрывных пробела (&nbsp;). Он как-то trim`oм вырезается? Или только регулярками?

Comment: `myString = myString.Substring(0, myString.Length - 2);` ?

Comment: Так не получится, проэкт большой и нужно гибкое решение, если бы можно было в тупую выделить сабстринг, я бы уже давно это сделал)

Comment: str.Replace("&nbsp;", "");

Comment: `Trim('\u00A0')` Обрезаем [Неразрывный пробел](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Неразрывный_пробел), если там действительно этот символ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если строка не декодированная, то используй декодер - [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.htmldecode).

После того, как получишь декодированную строку можно удалить пробелы следующим образом:

```
var html = "_Linked_5d2c9d64b&nbsp;&nbsp;";
var notHtml = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(html);
var result = Regex.Replace(notHtml, @"\s", " ").Trim(' ');
```

С помощью регулярного выражения ты заменяешь все типы пробелов на обычный, а после обрезаешь их обычным методом.